# Expression for Probability of Being Between Two Poisson Random Variables?

Tags: poisson-distribution, discrete-distributions

I have two independent Poisson random variables $A \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_A)$ and $B \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_B)$. For a fixed given integer $k$, I'd like to determine

$$P(A < k \leq A + B).$$

Is there an analytical expression for this probability as a function of $k, \lambda_A, \lambda_B$?

---

Edit 1: Is the following approach valid?

$$P(A < k \leq A + B) = 1 - P(A < k \leq A + B)^C $$

where $\cdot^C$ denotes the complement. The complement here is given by

$$P(A < k \leq A + B)^C = P(A \geq k) + P(k > A + B) $$

Plugging the complement in gives us:

\begin{align*}
P(A < k \leq A + B) &= 1 - P(A < k \leq A + B)^C\\
&= 1 - P(A \geq k) - P(k > A + B)\\
&= 1 - (1 - P(A < k)) - P(A + B < k)\\
&= P(A \leq k - 1) - P(A + B \leq k-1)
\end{align*}

where the final expression is the CDF of $A$ up to $k-1$ minus the CDF of $A+B$ up to $k-1$.

Is this correct? And if so, can I simplify further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, you can write:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(A < k \leqslant A+B)
&= \mathbb{P}(A+B \geqslant k) - \mathbb{P}(A \geqslant k) \\[6pt]
&= [1-\mathbb{P}(A+B \leqslant k-1)] - [1-\mathbb{P}(A \leqslant k-1)] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(A \leqslant k-1) - \mathbb{P}(A+B \leqslant k-1) \\[6pt]
&= F_\text{Pois}(k-1 | \lambda_A) - F_\text{Pois}(k-1 | \lambda_A+\lambda_B). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

The CDF of the Poisson distribution does not simplify any more than writing it as a sum of the mass values, so this is really can't simplify any more than this.  (As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) notes in the comments, you can "simplify" it to an integral if you prefer, but this will still require computer evaluation.)  You can compute this probability in `R` using standard probability functions for the Poisson distribution.  Here is an example taking $k=6$, $\lambda_A=3$ and $\lambda=6$.

```
#Set parameters
K <- 6
LAMBDA.A <- 3
LAMBDA.B <- 5

#Compute probability
ppois(K-1, lambda = LAMBDA.A + LAMBDA.B, lower.tail = FALSE) - 
  ppois(K-1, lambda = LAMBDA.A, lower.tail = FALSE)

[1] 0.724846
```

Comment: When I simplify my final expression for the difference of two CDFs, I get a much nicer expression: $F(A \leq k) - F(A+B\leq k) = e^{-\lambda_A}\Big[\sum_{x=0}^k \frac{\lambda_A^x - e^{-\lambda_B}(\lambda_A + \lambda_B)^x}{x!} \Big]$. I'm having trouble showing this to be equivalent to your final expression. Could you check my math?

Comment: I have made a major edit to simplify the solution.

Comment: I'm going to implement some Monte Carlo simulations to check the correctness, and if the formula hold, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ben, is there no way to make use of the Skellam distribution or one of its properties to further simplify? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution

Comment: It won't make things any simpler, since you will still end up with an equivalent expression.

Comment: You can simplify the answer to $(\Gamma(k)^{-1})\int_{\lambda_A}^{\lambda_A+\lambda_B} t^{k-1} e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t.$

Comment: @whuber thank you! Can you explain how you got there?

Comment: Rylan, it's based on the connection between the counts of events in a Poisson process and the waiting times between them.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/287025/919.

Comment: Ben, that's a great simplification but it could use just a little more explaining, because the first step is not generally true.  It relies on $B$ being non-negative.