# Using scipy poisson, is it possible to calculate lambda if given random variable (k) and cumulative density function (p) when k is a large value?

Tags: python, poisson-distribution, scipy

I'm learning the Poisson distribution and am trying to "backward" calculate lambda if given a random value (k) and cumulative density function value (p). My k value is rather large, over 200, and I'm not even sure if using the poisson is a good idea since it's just looking like a normal distribution at this point. Either way, I'm still interested in trying to figure out if it's possible to calculate lambda given k and p.

I tried to figure it out on my own but I have no clue where to start or how to accomplish this. Ultimately, I'd like to use `scipy.stat poisson`.

For example, if I have a value of k=400 and p=0.9, I would like to find the value of lambda which would end up being approximately 375.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
k=400
poisson(mu=375).cdf(k)
```

If anybody knows how to solve this and can help me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The value can be computed with as a quantile of a Gamma distribution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467341.

Comment: I looked at the link but still don't understand how to do it. Can you show an example calculation?

Comment: I spell out the relationship more explicitly at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/287025/919.